# dll compiled in release mode without \debug going really slow during debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I created a dll from the source code of a library and I compiled it in release mode without \DEBUG option.

I use this dll in another project created by myself with VC++ 2010 Express.
When I run my software with the "start debugging" button, a call to a particular function in the dll takes almost 2 minutes, but when I run my software without debugging, that very same dll function takes only 5 seconds to execute.

Of course I have all the interest in debugging my code, but I have no interest in waiting 2 minutes for the dll to execute in debug mode, because I do not want to debug the dll but my code and having to wait 2 minutes every time I want to debug my code is extremely annoying.

Is there any way not to debug the dll code as well, when I run "start debugging" in vc++ 2010 express?

Thank you

Comment: can you use 'jump over' instead of 'jump into' in the IDE when it gets to the function in your DLL?

Comment: Kevin: I do not understand this one, could you clarify please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following setting:
C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format -> Disabled

PDB files are generated if a project is built by using the /Zi or /ZI (Produce PDB Information) compiler switch, together with the /DEBUG (Generate Debug Info) linker switch. The compiler-generated PDB files are combined and written into a single PDB file that is placed in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Do I have to do this one when I compile the dll?

Comment: @Marco - Yes, if you specify this option then .pdb won't get generated and when you start debugging it won't load debug symbols since it will not be there